# How to set ImageViews source dynamically from ArrayList<String> with Drawable image name?

Tags: android, listview, imageview, drawable

I have a ListView with an ImageView, a TextView and another ImageView in each row.

The code below is the xml of my ListView row:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="60dp"
android:background="#FFF">
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/left"
android:layout_width="50dp"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:src="@drawable/ic_default"
android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />
<TextView
android:id="@+id/text"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:gravity="center"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:textSize="16sp" />
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/right"
android:layout_width="50dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:src="@drawable/ic_cena_play"
android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
android:clickable="true"
android:background="@drawable/mybuttonplay" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I have an ArrayList < String > with the names of Drawables I want to put in the first ImageView of the rows. I want to change the ImageViews source "ic_default" to the ones which have the name in ArrayList, dinamically.

In my Activity, inside onCreate(), I am using an Adapter, as the code below:

```
ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList();
items.add("Star");
items.add("Moon");
items.add("Dog");
items.add("Bird");
items.add("Tree");
ArrayList<String> itemsimg = new ArrayList();
itemsimg.add("ic_star");
itemsimg.add("ic_moon");
itemsimg.add("ic_dog");
itemsimg.add("ic_bird");
itemsimg.add("ic_tree");
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.scenesrow, R.id.text, items) {
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View row =  super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            ImageView left = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.left);
            //here I want to change the resource
            //Like if I had a function called getRosourceId(). DOES IT EXIST?!
            int x = getResourceId( itemsimg.get(position) );
            left.setImageResource(x);
            View right = row.findViewById(R.id.right);
            right.setTag(position);
            right.setOnClickListener(ScenesActivity.this);
            return row;
        }
    };
```

**Updated**

Thanks for answers! Now I can change the ImageView source dinamically **(but not yet from the ArrayList < String >)**. The setImageResource() method was not available before because I had a View. With the cast to ImageView you all suggested, big part of the problem was okay. But the answers do not cover the dinamically thing of the "name of the resource".

The last problem now is the left.setImageResource(resId); method asks for an ID from Resource, and I have a String. How to do it?

And sorry, other code version had some mistakes. Now it is fixed. I think the last problem is clear now.

Comment: I think create custom pojo class(getter/Setter method) and create custom adapter you have change image easily using Custom adapter and pojo class

Comment: because you are using `View` instead of `ImageView`, see my answer to do your job

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.scenesrow, R.id.text, items) {
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row =  super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        ImageView left = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.left);
        left.setOnClickListener(ScenesActivity.this);
        ImageView right = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.right);
        right.setTag(position);

       right.setImageResource(itemsimg.get(position));
       left.setImageResource(itemsimg.get(position));

       right.setOnClickListener(ScenesActivity.this);
       return row;
    }
```

change itemsimg with:

```
ArrayList<Integer> itemsimg = new ArrayList<Integer>();
itemsimg.add(R.drawable.ic_star);
itemsimg.add(R.drawable.ic_moon);
itemsimg.add(R.drawable.ic_dog);
itemsimg.add(R.drawable.ic_bird);
itemsimg.add(R.drawable.ic_tree);
```

for getting `drawableId` with String you can do this:

```
Context context = imageView.getContext();
int id = context.getResources().getIdentifier("ic_tree", "drawable", context.getPackageName());
imageView.setImageResource(id);
```

It's not efficient, but it works to look up occasional resources.

Comment: That is not a way to get the "R.drawable.ic_star" integer from a string "ic_star"? I think it should resolve the last problem.

Comment: you must use Integer and if you need last part ("ic_star") you need use `substring` method to get that , or store in another Array

Comment: see my Edit @SarahSakamoto and change the `itemsImg`

Comment: But this way you are inserting the integers from Drawable, not getting it dynamically based on String information. I want a way to convert strings into the respective drawable resource id. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 3):

Try this::

```
right.setImageResource(R.drawable.addphoto);/*select a picture from drawable*/
```

same for left also

```
left.setImageResource(R.drawable.addphoto);/*select a picture from drawable*/
```

**After Discussion**

```
       ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList();
    items.add("ic_star");
    items.add("ic_moon");
    items.add("ic_dog");
    items.add("ic_bird");
    items.add("ic_tree");
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.scenesrow, R.id.text, items) {
            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                View row =  super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
/*View : not required to declare everytimes*/
                ImageView left = row.findViewById(R.id.left);
                left.setOnClickListener(ScenesActivity.this);
                ImageView right = row.findViewById(R.id.right);
                right.setTag(position);
                right.setOnClickListener(ScenesActivity.this);
                right.setImageResource(R.drawable.addphoto);/*select a picture from drawable*/
                left.setImageResource(R.drawable.addphoto);/*select a picture from drawable*/

                return row;
            }
        };
```

Comment: The problem is the method setImageResource() is not available

Comment: Now I got the Bitmap, but without the method to set the image resource, I dont know what to do.

Comment: Your problem is Adapter class. there is some mistake in adapter class. I will let you know

Comment: please post full adapter class. Your adapter class is not in proper way

Answer (score 2):

Replace your code like this:

```
ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList();
items.add("ic_star");
items.add("ic_moon");
items.add("ic_dog");
items.add("ic_bird");
items.add("ic_tree");
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.scenesrow, R.id.text, items) {
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View row =  super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            ImageView left = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.left);
            left.setOnClickListener(ScenesActivity.this);
            left.setImageResource(R.drawable.leftphoto);
            ImageView right = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.right);
            right.setTag(position);
            right.setOnClickListener(ScenesActivity.this);
            right.setImageResource(R.drawable.rightphoto);
            return row;
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Another easy and structured way to do this:

1)add the resources in your **drawable** folder, lets suppose (ic_home,ic_launcher,ic_logout) //you can add any number of images

2)add these names in the **strings.xml** present in the values folder along with the names which will be displayed besides the image. It would look something like this...

```
 <!-- Drawer List Items -->
<string-array name="nav_drawer_items">
    <item>Home</item>
    <item>Add Category</item>
    <item>Logout</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="nav_drawer_icons">
    <item>ic_home</item>
    <item>ic_addcategory</item>
    <item>ic_logout</item>
</string-array>
```

3) Now create a pojo(getter/setter) class which will hold the icon text and icon id in a object. Something like this..

```
public class DrawerItems {

private String icnName;
private int icnId;

/**
 * @return the icnName
 */
public String getIcnName() {
    return icnName;
}

/**
 * @param icnName
 *            the icnName to set
 */
public void setIcnName(String icnName) {
    this.icnName = icnName;
}

/**
 * @return the imageid
 */
public int getIcnId() {
    return icnId;
}

/**
 * @param imageid
 *            the imageid to set
 */
public void setIcnId(int imageid) {
    icnId = imageid;
}}
```

4) Now we would need to populate this before giving it to the adapter. We could do this in this manner

```
private DrawerItems navigationDrawerItems;
private ArrayList<DrawerItems> dataObjects;
private String[] mDrawerListItems;
private String[] mDrawerIcons;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // to fetch the resources from the string files
    mDrawerListItems = getResources().getStringArray(
            R.array.nav_drawer_items);
    mDrawerIcons = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

    // drawerListAdapter = new DrawerListAdapter(this, mDrawerListItems);
    dataObjects = new ArrayList<DrawerItems>();
    for (int i = 0; i < mDrawerListItems.length; i++) {
        navigationDrawerItems = new DrawerItems();
        navigationDrawerItems.setIcnName(mDrawerListItems[i]);
        navigationDrawerItems.setIcnId(getResources().getIdentifier(
                mDrawerIcons[i], "drawable", this.getPackageName()));
        dataObjects.add(navigationDrawerItems);
    }

    drawerListAdapter = new DrawerListAdapter(this,
            R.layout.list_drawer_row_item, dataObjects);//add name of your layout
}
```

5) Now in adapter you could implement it this way

public class DrawerListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

```
private Context mContext;
private ArrayList<DrawerItems> mDataObjects;
private int layout;

public DrawerListAdapter(Context context, int resource,
        ArrayList<DrawerItems> dataObjects) {
    super(context, resource, dataObjects);
    mContext = context;
    mDataObjects = dataObjects;
    layout = resource;
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;

    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        convertView = inflater.inflate(layout, parent,
                false);

        holder.txtDrawerListItem = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.txt_drawer_item_name);
        holder.imgDrawerListIcon = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.img_drawer_item_icon);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    final DrawerItems dataObj = mDataObjects.get(position);
    holder.txtDrawerListItem.setText(dataObj.getIcnName());
    holder.imgDrawerListIcon.setImageResource(dataObj.getIcnId());

    return convertView;
}

public static class ViewHolder {
    TextView txtDrawerListItem;
    ImageView imgDrawerListIcon;
}
}
```

6) You are all set...make sure you have initialized views and common stuff